# Validar un campo select2 con jquery-validate

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

buenas tengo un formulario en el cual mediante una consulta desde php a mi bd  cargo un select, en el que uso la libreria select2 para poder buscar en el mis registros.. mi problema es que al validar este campo con jquery-validate este parece ignorarlo y no lo valida, alquien tiene una idea de como solucionar esto?
les dejo el codigo html de mi select y las reglas de validacion en mi script.

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="form-label">Ciudad</label>
  <select class="select2" id="ciudad" name="ciudad">
    <option>Seleccione una ciudad</option>
    <?php
     foreach ($getciudad as $id => $nombre)
       echo '<option  value="',$id,'">'.$nombre.'</option>';
    ?> 
  </select>
</div>
```

```js
$('document').ready(function(){

$(".select2").select2();

$('#form').validate({
      rules: {
        ciudad:{
          required: true
        }
      },
      messages: {
        ciudad: {
          required: "Este campo es requerido."
        }
      },
      highlight: function (input) {
        $(input).parents('.form-group').addClass('has-danger');
      },
      unhighlight: function (input) {
        $(input).parents('.form-group').removeClass('has-danger');
      },
      errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
        $(element).parents('.form-group').append(error);
      },
      submitHandler : function(_form){
        var form = $(_form);
        $.ajax({
          url: form.attr('action'),
          type: form.attr('method'),
          data: form.serialize(),
          dataType: 'json',
          success:function(response){
          ...
          }
        })
      }
    }); 
});
```

Answer (score 9):

Debido a que la validación del formulario no valida elementos ocultos, le tienes que indicar que tiene que validar esos elementos ocultos con la propiedad `ignore:[]`.

Posteriormente este validaría el `select` pero cada vez que cambie no volvería a validar y eso es un problema para eso hay que aplicar la validación cada vez que se haga un cambio en el `select`.

```
$select.on('change', function() {
  $(this).trigger('blur');
});
```

Una vez teniendo esos cambios agregamos una regla al plugin para que valide el `select2` ya que este no cuenta con el atributo `name`.

```
$select.rules('add', {
  required: true,
  messages: {
    required: "Seleccione una Opcion"
  }
});
```

> **Nota:**
>   Esto puede tener problemas cuando se utiliza Ajax en el select2.

Te dejo un ejemplo funcionando

```js
(function() {
  var $select = $('select').select2({
    placeholder: 'Choose',
    allowClear: true
  });

  /*
   * Aplicando la validacion del select cada vez que cambie
   */
  $select.on('change', function() {
    $(this).trigger('blur');
  });

  /*
   * Permitiendo la validacion de campos ocultos
   */
  $('#myForm').validate({
    ignore: '.select2-input, .select2-focusser',
    submitHandler: function(form) {
      alert("enviado")
    },
    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
      $(element).next().append(error);
    }
  });

  /*
   * agregando la validacion del select 
   * ya que no tiene un atributo name el plugin
   */
  $select.rules('add', {
    required: true,
    messages: {
      required: "Seleccione una Opcion"
    }
  });

}());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.16.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.min.js"></script>

<form id="myForm">
  <select name="country" id="country" style="width:200px">
    <option></option>
    <option value="US">United States</option>
    <option value="CA">Canada</option>
  </select>
  <br/>
  <button type="submit">Go</button>
</form>
```

Este es un ejemplo con `ajax` tomando como ejemplo el de la pagina de Select2

```js
function formatRepo(repo) {
  if (repo.loading) return repo.text;

  var markup = "<div class='select2-result-repository clearfix'>" +
    "<div class='select2-result-repository__avatar'><img src='" + repo.owner.avatar_url + "' /></div>" +
    "<div class='select2-result-repository__meta'>" +
    "<div class='select2-result-repository__title'>" + repo.full_name + "</div>";

  if (repo.description) {
    markup += "<div class='select2-result-repository__description'>" + repo.description + "</div>";
  }

  markup += "<div class='select2-result-repository__statistics'>" +
    "<div class='select2-result-repository__forks'><i class='fa fa-flash'></i> " + repo.forks_count + " Forks</div>" +
    "<div class='select2-result-repository__stargazers'><i class='fa fa-star'></i> " + repo.stargazers_count + " Stars</div>" +
    "<div class='select2-result-repository__watchers'><i class='fa fa-eye'></i> " + repo.watchers_count + " Watchers</div>" +
    "</div>" +
    "</div></div>";

  return markup;
}

function formatRepoSelection(repo) {
  return repo.full_name || repo.text;
}

(function() {
  var $select = $('select').select2({
    placeholder: 'Choose',
    allowClear: true,
    ajax: {
      url: "https://api.github.com/search/repositories",
      dataType: 'json',
      delay: 250,
      data: function(params) {
        return {
          q: params.term, // search term
          page: params.page
        };
      },
      processResults: function(data, params) {
        // parse the results into the format expected by Select2
        // since we are using custom formatting functions we do not need to
        // alter the remote JSON data, except to indicate that infinite
        // scrolling can be used
        params.page = params.page || 1;

        return {
          results: data.items,
          pagination: {
            more: (params.page * 30) < data.total_count
          }
        };
      },
      cache: true
    },
    escapeMarkup: function(markup) {
      return markup;
    },
    minimumInputLength: 1,
    templateResult: formatRepo,
    templateSelection: formatRepoSelection
  });

  /*
   * Aplicando la validacion del select cada vez que cambie
   */
  $select.on('change', function() {
    $(this).trigger('blur');
  });

  /*
   * Permitiendo la validacion de campos ocultos
   */
  $('#myForm').validate({
    ignore: '.select2-input, .select2-focusser',
    submitHandler: function(form) {
      alert("enviado")
    },
    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
      $(element).next().append(error);
    }
  });

  /*
   * agregando la validacion del select 
   * ya que no tiene un atributo name el plugin
   */
  $select.rules('add', {
    required: true,
    messages: {
      required: "Seleccione una Opcion"
    }
  });

}());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.16.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.min.js"></script>

<form id="myForm">
  <select name="country" id="country" style="width:200px">
    <option></option>
    <option value="US">United States</option>
    <option value="CA">Canada</option>
  </select>
  <br/>
  <button type="submit">Go</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 4):

El único error que tiene tu código, es que al `<option>Seleccione una ciudad</option>`, le falta el atributo `value=""`

Ejemplo:

```js
$('document').ready(function() {

  $(".select2").select2();

  $('#form').validate({
    rules: {
      ciudad: {
        required: true
      }
    },
    messages: {
      ciudad: {
        required: "Este campo es requerido."
      }
    },
    highlight: function(input) {
      $(input).parents('.form-group').addClass('has-danger');
    },
    unhighlight: function(input) {
      $(input).parents('.form-group').removeClass('has-danger');
    },
    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
      $(element).parents('.form-group').append(error);
    },
    submitHandler: function(_form) {
      console.log('Vale!');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.select2 {
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.16.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.min.js"></script>

<form id="form">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="form-label">Ciudad</label>
    <select class="select2" name="ciudad">
      <option value="">Seleccione una ciudad</option>
      <option value="id">Ciudad</option>
    </select><br/>
    <button>Validar</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

-

Adicionalmente si quieres se auto-valide tras seleccionar una opción entonces puedes hacer lo siguiente:

- Al instanciar el `select2`, te puedes suscribir al evento [`select2:select`](http://select2.github.io/options.html#events), el cual se dispara cuando el valor del `select` ha sido modificado por el `select2`.
- Entonces para notificarle al `validate` puedes disparar un evento `blur` sobre el elemento `select`.

Ejemplo:

```js
$('document').ready(function() {

  $(".select2")
    .select2()
    .on('select2:select', function() {
      $(this).trigger('blur');
    });

  $('#form').validate({
    rules: {
      ciudad: {
        required: true
      }
    },
    messages: {
      ciudad: {
        required: "Este campo es requerido."
      }
    },
    highlight: function(input) {
      $(input).parents('.form-group').addClass('has-danger');
    },
    unhighlight: function(input) {
      $(input).parents('.form-group').removeClass('has-danger');
    },
    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
      $(element).parents('.form-group').append(error);
    },
    submitHandler: function(_form) {
      console.log('Vale!');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.select2 {
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.16.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.min.js"></script>

<form id="form">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="form-label">Ciudad</label>
    <select class="select2" name="ciudad">
      <option value="">Seleccione una ciudad</option>
      <option value="id">Ciudad</option>
    </select><br/>
    <button>Validar</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

Esta es la forma con la que yo valido un selector por cliente:

**Archivo html:**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.16.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
```

**Archivo js:**

```
$.validator.addMethod("validaSelect", function(value, element, arg){
  return arg != value;
 }, "Seleccione una opción");

$('#form').validate({
      rules:{
        ciudad:{
            validaSelect: "SELECCIONE UNA OPCIÓN"
        }
    },
messages:{
        pais:"Introduzca una ciudad válida"
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**SOLUCIONADO: "VALIDACION" EN FORM VALIDATE CON SELECT2**

En mi html:

```
<form id="form-compras" name="form-compras" method="POST">
  <!-- Tipo de comprobante -->
  <div class="col-lg-4" id="content-tipo-comprobante">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="tipo_comprobante">Tipo Comprobante <sup class="text-danger">*</sup></label>
      <select name="tipo_comprobante" id="tipo_comprobante" class="form-control select2" onchange="default_val_igv(); modificarSubtotales(); ocultar_comprob();" placeholder="Seleccinar un tipo de comprobante">
        <option value="Ninguno">Ninguno</option>
        <option value="Boleta">Boleta</option>
        <option value="Factura">Factura</option>
        <option value="Nota_de_venta">Nota de venta</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

En mi **JS:**

```
//Initialize Select2 TIPO DE COMPROBANTE
$("#tipo_comprobante").select2({
  theme: "bootstrap4",
  placeholder: "Selecione Comprobante",
  allowClear: true,
});

// .....::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::: V A L I D A T E   F O R M  :::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::..
$(function () {
  // Aplicando la validacion del select cada vez que cambie
  $("#tipo_comprobante").on("change", function () { $(this).trigger("blur"); });
  
  // Form validate
  $("#form-compras").validate({
    ignore: ".select2-input, .select2-focusser",
    rules: { tipo_comprobante: { required: true }, },
    messages: { tipo_comprobante: { required: "Campo requerido" }, },
    errorElement: "span",
    errorPlacement: function (error, element) { error.addClass("invalid-feedback"); element.closest(".form-group").append(error); },
    highlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) { $(element).addClass("is-invalid").removeClass("is-valid"); },
    unhighlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) { $(element).removeClass("is-invalid").addClass("is-valid"); },
    submitHandler: function (form) { guardar_y_editar_registro(form); },
  });

  //agregando la validacion del select  ya que no tiene un atributo name el plugin
  $("#tipo_comprobante").rules("add", { required: true, messages: { required: "Campo requerido" } });
});
```

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).